# Flutter Build Apk Error "Unresolved reference: snackbar"

Tags: android, kotlin, flutter, stripe-payments, flutter-dependencies

I'm currently making an e-commerce project using flutter. I need a payment gateway to make transactions, so I install the "stripe_payment" package (https://pub.dev/packages/stripe_payment).

After I followed the installation steps, I run the "flutter run" command. The result is the package stripe can run well in my application.

However, when I run the "flutter build apk", an error appears as below:

[image]

The main errors are:
e: C:\Users\samue\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\stripe_payment-1.0.5\android\src\main\kotlin\de\jonasbark\stripepayment\StripeDialog.kt: (6, 36): Unresolved reference: snackbar

When I open the C:\Users\samue\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\stripe_payment-1.0.5\android\src\main\kotlin\de\jonasbark\stripepayment\StripeDialog.kt file and I check line 6, I see inside the file importing import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar. 
[image]

Then I looked for a solution on google, it looks like the problem is build.gradle. Here I attach the contents of the file from build.gradle

[image]

But I tried editing the build.gradle dependencies section that I got from Google, but all of them didn't work. When I run the flutter build apk, the same error still appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. I deleted the package "search_widget", then the package "stripe_payment" can run normally again without any errors during the build.

From this problem, I just understood that there are possibilities that packages on flutter can conflict, causing errors.